# Asynchronous UDP server/client as base for IPC in Haskell

Tags: haskell, udp, messaging

I want to put together the basics for asynchronous UDP IPC in Haskell. For this the sender/receiver should issue e.g. an synchronous receive (or send, depending from what side you view it) thread and carry on with other tasks.

This might involve to define a new data type that consists of optional message/data serial numbers and some sort of buffer so that the send thread can stop sending when it gets a notification from the receiver that it cannot cope with the speed.

I aim to make this as light weight & asynchronous as possible.

I have tried a number of things such as starting a new receive thread for every packet (took this approach from a paper about multi player online games), but this was grinding almost everything to a halt.

Below is my innocent first take on this. Any help on e.g. creating buffers, creating serial numbers or a DCCP implementation (that I could not find) in Haskell appreciated. - ***I would not like to get into opinionated discussions about UDP vs TCP etc..***

My snippet stops working once something gets out of sync e.g. when no data arrives any more or when less data arrives than expected. I am looking as said for some way of lightweight (featherweight :D) sync between the send and the receive thread of for an example of such.

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
        s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
        hostAddr <- inet_addr host
        done <- newEmptyMVar
        let p = B.pack "ping"
        thread <- forkIO $ receiveMessages s done
        forM_ [0 .. 10000] $ \i -> do
              sendAllTo s (B.pack  "ping") (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
        takeMVar done
        killThread thread
        sClose s
        return()

receiveMessages :: Socket ->  MVar () -> IO ()
receiveMessages socket done = do
        forM_ [0 .. 10000] $ \i -> do
              r <- recvFrom socket 1024
              print (r) --this is a placeholder to make the fun complete
        putMVar done ()
```

Comment: IMHO your snippet isn't near to do anything of what your text says that you would like it todo, maybe I'm missing something ? Are you trying to do RBUDP (http://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=itj.2009.600.604)

Answer (score 1):

[If you don't trust your messenger, you can never agree on anything -- not even a single bit like "are we done yet"!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance)

Comment: I do trust the messenger. As laid out in DCCP RFC 4340, all that we perceive as unreliable probably is (in modern networks) a consequence of insufficient congestion control.

Comment: @JFritsch If you expect that it's possible to lose a packet, then you don't trust the messenger.